# library (xlsx) fatal error, R session aborted?

Tags: r, xlsx, coredump

I had encountered an issue when I was trying to run library (xlsx) on R.
it says R session has been aborted due to a fatal error.

also says: failed to write core dump. Core dump have been disabled.
I opened my MacOS's terminal and wrote " ulimit-c unlimited " and saved the change. reopened JAVA and R, run the library (xlsx), still got the session terminated.

Can anyone help?
Thank you so much :)

I opened my MacOS's terminal and wrote " ulimit-c unlimited " and saved the change.
reopened JAVA and R, run the library (xlsx), still got the session terminated.

ALso installed packages (xlsx, rJava)

Comment: "Trying to run" is too vague. Do you mean you did `library(xlsx)`  or that this happened after you loaded and you tried a specific function?

Comment: FYI I have found that the openxlsx package has fewer problems than the xlsx one.